# unknown value in XPath from WebService in InfoPath

Tags: xml, web-services, xpath, infopath

I have integrated a self built WebService in InfoPath.
an example xpath to an element is

```
/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/ns2:MyServiceResponse/ns2:MyServiceResult/MyService/data/mail
```

my problem are these **ns2:** because i have to change them to **tns:**

I assume they come from InfoPath since they are nowhere to be found in my xml Structure (which is actually a C# DataSet)

what i did:

- changed some stuff in my web service and watched if it changes something
- read the tutorial/syntax of XPath http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

where do they come from and how can i change them?

Comment: i figured out, ns comes from "Name Server" and mine is defined with "tempuri". does someone know how i can change this to tns?

Comment: What is it that you actually want to do? Namespaces are designed in such a way that they can be used with one prefix (`ns2`) in one place and another prefix (`tns`) in another place as long as they are used consistently in each context. InfoPath automatically assigns prefixes to the namespaces used in secondary data connections (`ns2`, `ns3`, etc). This should not typically be a problem, so please tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: To put it more concisely: Why do you want to change them?

Comment: @JLRishe I have to replace a old WS with a new one and my company uses lots of InfoPath Forms, connected to this webservice. Now if i can manage to get the exact same XPaths for my new Web Service this will save us a lot of trouble.

I now managed to find the difference: Because i'm just testing the Service with dummy data i had not configured specific endpoints or Namespace attributes from the Service- or BehavoiurContracts which resulted in having my **tns (targetNamespace)** set to "tempuri.org" and because of that the actual address localhost:655... ended up beeing **ns2 (namespace 2)**.

Comment: But now that i specified the endpoints of my service and set the Namespace, infoPath won't take my Webservice as Datasource anymore. As soon as I want to choose a specific operation of my service i get an error saying "Type Conflict"